# SVN Repositories no longer appears in SmartSVN, says UUID is different if I commit changes

Tags: macos, svn, repository, smartsvn

I am having this issue now for several days now. Something happened. I can't commit to my SVN Repository, if I do, I get this error

> Commit: Repository UUID '49a14762-82d3-4890-9de1-d63348e82a44' doesn't
>   match expected UUID 'c8d17b73-fbff-4d6e-b104-923b936b9cd2'

I played with command line (Terminal) commands but could not resolve the issue. If try to to checkout the repository again, I don't see anything there. There used to be a lot of project but right now it is empty.

[image]

What am I missing, how to fix this problem? I am using Mac ox X Mavericks. I have just downloaded SmartSVN 8.5 still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up backing up my working folder. Removed all .svn and .ds_store from the folder as well as other .projects and hidden files. Create a new repository in SmartSVN and imported it from my (cleaned) working copy. Now everything working. Unfortunately I could not fix the actual problem. The problem was most likely caused when installed eclipse svn plugins.

This is the [command](http://danilo.ariadoss.com/how-to-recursively-remove-ds_store-files-on-mac-os-x/) to clean .svn and hidden files on mac

```
find . -name '*.DS_Store' -type f -delete  #run this in working folder.
find . -name '*.svn' -type f -delete
```

Alternatively use the following [command](http://lifehacker.com/188892/show-hidden-files-in-finder) to show hidden files in Finder and then remove by selecting it

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```